# How to add facets to an IntelliJ Java/Gradle project to create a self-sufficient war

Tags: intellij-idea, war, gradle, netflix

**Background**

1. Download and install IntelliJ 12.04 Community Edition
2. Create project from external source (point to Gradle build script)
3. Specify JDK 7 as project's SDK

*Note: Project is open source at github:  Netflix/karyon*

**Problem**

Want to simply war the project.  In playing on the commercial version with GAE plugin installed, I was able to specify the Web Application facet, and create the war via the artifact functionality.  With the setup described above, the only available facet is Android.

**Question**

How can I create a self sufficient war (includes all dependencies and hence can be dropped in any container without additional classpath requirements) from within the IDE?

Comment: Community Edition [lacks J2EE support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), you will have to do it with some other tools like Maven.

Comment: Thanks.  Answer with above comment and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community edition [doesn't have Java EE support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), you need to use some other tool for packaging the war (e.g. Maven).