# How to add web facet and artifiacts to a module in gradle for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, facet, artifacts

This post is not similar to this post:
[How to add facets to an IntelliJ Java/Gradle project to create a self-sufficient war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749485/how-to-add-facets-to-an-intellij-java-gradle-project-to-create-a-self-sufficient)

I am using the IntelliJ-IDEA 12.1.15 Ultimate, just started working on gradle with IDEA.
Previously, we have a gradle setup for Eclipse which is working.

I am using the:
apply plugin 'idea'

Can't figure out how to add settings for web facet and artifacts, have read the gradle documentation as well and various other posts but no clue yet.

There are some workaround found about manually adding the web-facet or editing the IntelliJ XMl project files from within the Gradle build script. But these seem too much of an effort, considering how it easy it is to add all this for gradle-eclipse.

So the question - Is there a clean solution for doing this? Like just making a build.gradle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer version intelliJ 13 supports this out of the box. So just upgrade, or use a intellij-gradle-plugin (search google) for older version I haven't tested this plugin myself but read somewhere that it works.